# команда USE Sercver в запросе

Tags: c#, sql-server

Господа, прошу объяснить не мыслимое

Есть простой запрос, который у меня работает, и в C# и в МС студии

```
//c#
string slim_sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM sys.Tables";
//Ms SQL Server Management Studio
SELECT * FROM sys.Tables
```

Но на некоторых серверах таблички не находятся, в студии делаю по другому

```
//Ms SQL Server Management Studio
Use MyServerName
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.Tables
```

А как это же самое реализовать на c# ?

```
//p.s.
string slim_sqlquery = "Use MyServerName GO SELECT * FROM sys.Tables";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(slim_sqlquery, conn_my_servak);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();//вот тут лезут ошибки, что SQL запрос надо в 1 строку
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SqlClient не понимает `GO` так, как это делает SSMS.

Либо используйте *three-part naming*:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM MyServerName.sys.Tables", conn_my_servak);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Либо вынесите смену контекста в отдельную команду:

```
conn_my_servak.ChangeDatabase("MyServerName");

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sys.Tables", conn_my_servak);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Answer (score 2):

В Запросе `Use MyServerName GO` убери.

```
   using (var connection = new SqlConnection(conn_my_servak))
   {
          connection.Open();
          using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
          {
                command.CommandText("SELECT * FROM sys.Tables") 
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) 
                {
                      while(reader.Read())
                      {
                            SomeId = (int)reader["id"];
                            SomeString = reader["someStr"].ToString();
                            .....
                      }
                }
          }


    }
```

Comment: этот ответ и выше - оба проканали. по таким ответам надо книги писать ) принял верхний, т.к. нельзя принять 2